# Alternative to a BAT file to open an application with arguments?

Tags: windows, batch

A BAT file just does not look good to me in 2013 for such a simple task. Is there an easy alternative to that on Windows 7?

Comment: I am probably too old-fashioned but I am still using CMD files for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a shortcut to your program.

In shortcut properties, `Shortcut` tab, add the arguments to the `Target` field.

E.G.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" about:blank
```